# WPS Presentation is not able to play audio

Tags: sound, presentation, wps-office

I am using 18.04. LibreOffice was not able to play presentation's audio which is made in Windows. I installed WPS Presentation 2016 and 2019 for Linux and unfortunately now I cannot activate sound permission for WPS Presentation. Is there any way to enable all application permissions?

Comment: Please provide specific details as to what OS & release you're using; the linux kernel is currently in version 5.13 in the latest release of Ubuntu; and it could be decades before it reaches 18.x given it's taken from 1991 to 2021 and is still version 5.  You're likely using Ubuntu 18.04 LTS but that's a Linux or GNU/Linux distribution, but isn't the same thing as Linux 18.04.  Please clarify (non-Ubuntu's also use 18.04 so are using a non-Ubuntu 18.04?)